# Swift error after using pod install (clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 )

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, parse-platform, cocoapods

I've been trying to resolve this issue for 3 hours and I tried everything that's on the web but nothing seems to work, I'm just trying to add the (login in with Facebook) button on an app connected to parse.
I even started a new project from scratch to see if the same issue would appear and it did.

the error: (clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation))

It appeared after doing 'pod install' in both apps, this is what I have in my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.1'

xcodeproj 'carpoolup'

target :carpoolup, :exclusive => true do
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseUI'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'
pod 'ParseTwitterUtils'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
end
```

please help, what does this error mean?

Comment: what do you opening XCworkspace or XCProject?

Comment: Try adding `use_frameworks!` to your podfile

Comment: @RohitPradhan the XCworkspace, but I tried to open the project and it had the same error

Comment: @AddisonWebb Thank you so much!! this actually worked, I can't thank you enough, it really got on my nerves!

Comment: @KasemHato great! I added it as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `use_frameworks!` after the platform line to force cocoapods to use frameworks.

Example from cocoapods.org:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6'
  pod 'ORStackView', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3'
end
```